# Every time getting nil url for model in core data iOS

Tags: ios

I'm always getting `nil` in `url` in the following code:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSURL *url = [bundle URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

`bundle` is not `nil`, my model name is `Model.xcdatamodeld`

What can be wrong?

Comment: what is name of model in your project & also check bundle is not nill

Comment: bundle is not nil I verified it.

Comment: Why use `bundleForClass:` instead of `mainBundle`?

Comment: If we use mainbundle same problem occured.

Comment: Run `NSLog(@"%@", [NSBundle mainBundle].bundlePath)` on the simulator, open the printed path, and see if the expected file is there.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
 NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

I cleared the Model.xcdatamodeld remove it, add new DataModel.xcdatamodel in my code and restart the simulator, then I got modelURL.

Comment: "model.xcdatamodeld"? I thought you said it is called "Model.xcdatamodeld"?

Comment: Yes Model.xcdatamodeld

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is immediately obvious what bundleForClass is returning to you. Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleForClass:) say:

> - (NSBundle *)bundleForClass:(Class)aClass
>
> Return Value:
>
> The NSBundle object that dynamically loaded aClass (a loadable bundle), the NSBundle object for the framework in which aClass is defined, or the main bundle object if aClass was not dynamically loaded or is not defined in a framework.

It is only going to give you mainBundle under certain circumstances. You don't say what your class is. I think going straight to mainBundle (as you have done) is much safer.

Comment: In your original question you used the method bundleForClass to obtain the bundle you needed - which was mainBundle I presume. In your answer, which you said worked, you specifically called URLForResource on mainBundle. I think Apple's documentation is saying that you only get mainBundle from bundleForClass if the class is not dynamically loaded or part of a framework. I don't know what class you are using, but perhaps it is one of those that does not result in mainBundle being returned.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] resourceURL];
```

instead of

```
[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
```